# Android: Allow User To Create A Custom Variable

Tags: java, android, variables, defined

I am building a financial application where the user has 2 or 3 text fields. One will be the name of the income/expense, one will be the amount, and the other a "note" that the user can input to remind themselves of what it was. How can I, when the user presses "enter", create a variable with that name and value to use in calculations later. I want to use the data they enter and display it on another activity and use it dynamically to calculate their balance. The name of the variable doesn't have to be exactly what they name it, but I need to be able to reference it in my calculations on another activity. Say I have a variable 'weeklyBalance'.
I want to be able to say weeklyBalance = weeklyBalance' +/- 'userDefinedVariables' Then print out their new balance, also creating a text field with their desired name and amount to display to them later.

A basic layout looks like this:
Name: Weekly Salary
Amount: 20.32
Note: My Weekly Salary
[Enter]

I'm brand new to android and this is the first big issue I've been having. Any help will be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: More data would be welcome: What is the real issue, how to store variables in the app in order to use them later or how to operate with that variable?

Comment: The issue is I want to create a variable when the user enters their data. I don't know how many variables will need to be created so I want them to be made when the user enters the data. Making pre-made variables wouldn't work because I don't know how many to make. Hence why I need them to be made when the user enters more income/expenses.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm explaining it right. Say the user wants to input a check they just got and name it "work" and it was for $5. How can I store that new information in a brand new variable and recall it on other activities. Say they wanted to add 20 new sources of income, I'd need 20 new variables and be able to recall them all independently on a different activity to list all the variable the user entered. I hope I'm being clear.

Answer (score 0):

Save them in a content provider which can later call the value when you need it.

Here is a good starting point:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to pass the data from Activity A to Activity B, correct me if i'm wrong.
What you can do is retrieve the data from "note" and pass it to activity B.
You can use

```
intent.putExtra("YOUR_TAG", note);
```

and retrieve it in activity B using

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
bundle.getString("ITEM_TITLE");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to permanently store some data in your application, I would suggest using a database. SQLite is very nicely integrated with Android and once you get an idea of how it works, it's really easy to use.

Check out here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mixing concepts "variables in your code" and "custom values".

I'd just save a collection of Variable objects, where you can check which equation uses each custom value and how (something like `new Variable(variableName,value,equation)`